# How to get a CLOB type returned by a stored procedure in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have an stored procedure in Oracle Database. This stored procedure returns a CLOB type. This CLOB type contains an embedded xml.
I use a DBlookup Mediator to call this stored procedure like this:

```
<dblookup>
<connection>
<pool>
<dsName>XeDS</dsName>
</pool>
</connection>
<statement>
 <sql>select  pkg_ws_sol_cursos.fu_listado_cursos(?,?) as resultado from dual</sql>
 <parameter xmlns:xs="http://www.example.es" expression="//xs:HASH" type="VARCHAR" />
 <parameter xmlns:xs="http://www.example.es" expression="//xs:PV2_I_LANGISO" type="VARCHAR" />
 <result name="resultado_p" column="resultado" />
</statement>
</dblookup>
```

When I get the value of the property "resultado_p" with the value returned by the stored procedure I realize that this value is incorrect. The returned value should be a string containing embedded xml, but not is the case. The returned value is a strig like this:
oracle.sql.CLOB@423435435435
I think this is the result of executing the toString method of the oracle.sql.CLOB java type, but I need to get the content of the CLOB and not the toString result.

Has anybody invoked an stored procedure returning CLOBs types??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DBMediators (DBLookup/DBReport) do not support advanced data types such as CLOB, BLOB, etc. out of the box. As you've rightly pointed out the value of the returned field is being tried to serialize to a string (as that's the default behaviour) without handling the data type properly and that's why you're observing the aforesaid behaviour.

If you want to deal with all the advanced data types/SQL logics, what we often recommend is to use WSO2 DSS (or dataservice features) which provide you with a complete stack of functionalities to be used against data manipulative operations. With that you can call any SQL logic starting from simple SELECTs to much rigorous Stored procedures with ease.

Answer (score 0):

try to use : 
SELECT sys_XMLGEN( pkg_ws_sol_cursos.fu_listado_cursos(?,?)  , XMLFormat('Result')).getClobVal() as resultado  from   dual